# Telerik MVC grid filter text column by substring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, filter, grid, telerik

I've spent hours searching a solution for this. We have a description column in a Telerik MVC Razor grid. We've enabled filtering, and the filtering, in a basic sense, works fine. However, we would like to be able to filter the text column more accurately. For example, if I do a Contains filter with the condition "**Hwy 20**", the grid returns every row with "**Hwy 20**", "**Hwy 201**", "**Hwy 20/41**", "**Hwy 205**", etc...

How can we get it to return ONLY records with "Hwy 20"?

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished by using filter extensions:

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(operators => operators
        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .StartsWith("Starts with")
            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
            .EndsWith("Ends with")
        ))
    )
```

See this [documentation url](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-filtering.html) for more information